# Laravel @section

Tags: php, frameworks

My view folder structure

- content

  - home.blade.php
- includes
- partials

  - mainsection.blade.php
- layout

  - default.blade.php

My home.blade.php

```
@extends('layout.default')

@section('content')

@section('partials.mainsection')
        <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 text-center">
               <h1>Some Text</h1>
        </div>
@stop
```

My mainsection.blade.php

```
<section class="section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
           @yield('section')
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

My default.blade.php

```
@include('layout.header')

<div id="wrapper">

    <header>
        <div class="container">
    @include('partials.mainNav')
        </div>
    </header>

    <div id="main">

    @yield('content')

    </div>


@include('layout.footer')

</div>
```

My thought was that i can take the partials.mainsection view for my content so that i dont have to write everytime the section / container / row code.
So i only write some text in @section('partials.mainsection') which is wrapped by the mainsection view.

But this does not work, what do i wrong or is there any other way to do this ?

The "partials.mainsection" is only my wrapper for my content(s) so i don't have to write this every time again. If i use just @include i can't extend it from each view.

Answer (score 0):

To include a partial or any other partial into your blade template the syntax is @include('view.name')

Comment: But if you just include the view you can extend it with your text.

Comment: see the first example on this page: http://laravel.com/docs/templates

they use `@parent` in their view partial, and `@section`, `@show` on the page they want to use it